# Avoid inserting duplicate attribut throught XmlWriter

Tags: c#, attributes, xmlreader, duplicates

I'm writing an xml through an XmlWriter and need to do something like this :

[...]

```
string myAttributeName = myWhatEverFunction(); // returning "balblablaName"
xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString(myAttributeName, "myValue");

myAttributeName = myWhatEverFunction(); // returning "balblablaName" again...
xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString(myAttributeName, "myValue2");
```

[...]

There is no XmlReader, and the program don't have a trace of what have been inserted before. Why ? Because the data is provided by an external Lua Script I can not modify. The c# code I expose here, is used as a Dll without any storage.

So, I would like to  figure out if the attribut I'm trying to insert is already inserted in order to avoid a "Duplicate Attribut exception"...

Any ideas ? :-/

Comment: `... and the program don't know if the attribut have already been inserted` then make your program **know** it.

Comment: Thanks, of course... But this is not my question. I would like to know how to avoid trying to insert an existing atrtibute using XmlWriter.

Comment: Why not store each attribute name in a [`HashSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) lookup? Before writing an attribute, check if it's already in your HashSet. If it is, ignore it. If it isn't, add it to the HashSet and write it to your XML.

Comment: Hello Chris. Why i cannot store each attribut ? Because the data is provided by an external Lua Script I can not modify. The c# code I expose here, is used as a Dll without any storage. So I'm trying to search a way to know if an attribut is already inserted before trying to insert it and falling on a duplicate exception. ^^